# What does IE8 not understand about this CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, submenu

What does IE8 not understand about this CSS?

```
.menu_links_hfp.block-type-navigation ul.menu li.current_page_item > ul.sub-menu,
.menu_links_hfp.block-type-navigation ul.menu li.current-menu-item > ul.sub-menu,
.menu_links_hfp.block-type-navigation ul.menu li.current_page_parent > ul.sub-menu
{
display: block !important;
position: relative !important;
left: auto !important;
visibility: visible !important;
}
```

I have a CSS problem with the left menu in IE8 in this page when hovering on this Wordpress site:
edit: here is the orig url http://www.wpcollege.nl/mytestpage/ (hover over submenu item  in the left menu in ie8 and see what happens)

What happens is that on a hover, things get messed up and it floats out to the right side of the parent. In ie8+, chrome, firefox no problems.

Do I have to add statements with :hover for ie8 only? I can add body class .ie8 to target ie8 only.

Any help much much appreciated. I am stuck ! Regards,

Comment: Please replace your short url with the original one.

Comment: the url is changed now to the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the hover popout controlled by JS or CSS? I can't seem to find it in your theme's stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that IE8 is throwing an error on a plugin called anyhover-effects? Sounds related; you might need to resolve that to get this working.

[image: screencap]

Comment: yes  I know that, this scripts will be disabled for IE8, but didn't think it would be related. I will check this. thanks for your suggestion.